# webpack loaders can't resolve some image files

Tags: css, webpack

I'm getting the following error:

```sh
ERROR in ./app/styles/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-1!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--12-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--12-3!./app/styles/index.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../images/global/univers/characters/border-universe-top.png' in '/home/wolf/app/styles'
 @ ./app/styles/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-1!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--12-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--12-3!./app/styles/index.scss) 81:42-115
 @ ./app/styles/index.scss
 @ ./app/core/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js ./app/core/app.js
```

Now, the weird parts:

- I made sure the path is correct
- In that very same SCSS file, another image file is used through `url()`. This file is in the same directory as `border-universe-top.png` and is loaded just fine.
- the two files are very similar (although it might not be relevant, they are both ~2kb)

I thought it might come from some webpack config options, but since some files are correctly resolved, I'm starting to winder if it might not come from something totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `npm rebuild node-sass` ?

I experienced this in the past and this resolved it.